# How to find connected components of a 3D CT scan Image using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, medical-imaging

I have some 3D CT scan images. Some slices of that image contains unnecessary things. I want remove that things giving the intensity value -1000. How can I do that?

Comment: may I suggest numpy tutorials. -- how do you read and "handle" that data? what libraries do you use?

Comment: I have used SimpleITK library to read image and convert to numpy array.

Comment: If I understand it right, just compare the array with the value -1000, to get a mask with true or false, and then use the mask to remove the things you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading with SimpleITK, here's how you can do it with SimpleITK

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

ct_image = sitk.ReadImage("your_ct_scan_here")

# produce a binary mask image for all pixels>-1000
mask_image = (ct_image>-1000)

# apply the mask to make a new image
new_ct_image = ct_image * mask_image

sitk.WriteImage(new_ct_image, "masked_ct_image.nii.gz")
```